# moodle TinyMCE not able to make links in IE11

Tags: php, tinymce, editor, moodle

I'm facing a problem with TinyMCE editor in Internet Explorer 11.0.1.
The inserted hyperlink is removed from HTML when using toolbar icon "Insert/edit link".
I am on Moodle 2.6 and it works all the other IE version and all the other browsers
Steps to reproduce:

1. select text in editor and click on toolbar icon "Insert/edit
   link"
2. enter your url and click insert button. You may notice that
   link is not being highlighted in editor, though toolbar icon "remove
   link" is activated
3. Click "view HTML" and you may notice that HTML
   A tag is placed as first element of parent element, with an empty
   content (should be selected text).
4. when you click again on
   TinyMCE editor area previously inserted A tag is removed from HTML
   markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade the TinyMCE.

here is the plugin link for upgrading

https://github.com/moodle/moodle/tree/master/lib/editor/tinymce/tiny_mce/3.5.10